# Need information to get scientific notation for the coefficient

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, lyx

Good afternoon everyone,

I wanted to know if anyone knows how to put scientific notation for the coefficient of a variable. If you look at my results you will agree with me that to get a table with a coefficient of  0,0000742 is not so good. Could you help me to find the command that will allow me to get 7,42.10^(-5)?

```
% 27 May 2014 16:10:14
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
detect-mode,
group-digits = false,
input-symbols = ( ) [ ] - +,
table-align-text-post = false,
input-signs = ,

}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Innovation regressions using several diversity dimensions. \label{tabl}}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ 
\begin{tabular}{l*{7}{c}{S[table-format=1.2,table-column-width=10mm]}}
\toprule

            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Full sample div\_cont}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Full sample div\_cont}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Full sample div25\_cont}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Full sample div25\_nat}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Full sample div25\_nat\_obs}\\

\hline
gdp\_pop     &   0,0000742       &   0.0000327         &    0.000142\sym{*}  &    0.000142\sym{*}  &   0.0000913         \\
            &      (1.56)         &      (0.52)         &      (2.32)         &      (2.32)         &      (1.24)         \\
[1em]
ind\_agri    &      0.0127\sym{**} &      0.0100         &      0.0174\sym{*}  &      0.0174\sym{*}  &      0.0183\sym{**} \\
            &      (2.93)         &      (1.93)         &      (2.71)         &      (2.71)         &      (3.11)         \\
[1em]
ln\_pop      &     -0.0158         &    -0.00404         &    -0.00720         &    -0.00708         &    -0.00881         \\
            &     (-1.20)         &     (-0.26)         &     (-0.34)         &     (-0.33)         &     (-0.31)         \\
[1em]
size\_area   &   0.0000254\sym{*}  &  0.00000644         &   0.0000158         &   0.0000157         &   0.0000132         \\
            &      (2.17)         &      (0.46)         &      (0.91)         &      (0.90)         &      (0.57)         \\
[1em]
human\_st    &      0.0515         &      0.0141         &     0.00257         &     0.00241         &      0.0505         \\
            &      (1.71)         &      (0.33)         &      (0.06)         &      (0.06)         &      (1.04)         \\
[1em]
sh\_for\_pop  &       2.982         &       2.629         &      -3.222         &      -3.244         &      -3.605         \\
            &      (0.77)         &      (0.63)         &     (-0.62)         &     (-0.62)         &     (-0.81)         \\
[1em]
div\_cont    &       5.790\sym{*}  &       3.758         &                     &                     &                     \\
            &      (2.28)         &      (1.33)         &                     &                     &                     \\
[1em]
y2000       &      -0.279         &                     &      -0.469         &      -0.468         &                     \\
            &     (-1.11)         &                     &     (-1.20)         &     (-1.21)         &                     \\
[1em]
educ        &                     &      0.0489\sym{*}  &                     &                     &                     \\
            &                     &      (2.28)         &                     &                     &                     \\
[1em]

div25\_cont  &                     &                     &      0.0825         &                     &                     \\
            &                     &                     &      (0.12)         &                     &                     \\
[1em]
div25\_nat   &                     &                     &                     &       0.212         &                     \\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (0.07)         &                     \\
[1em]
div25\_nat\_obs&                     &                     &                     &                     &       2.391         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (0.96)         \\
[1em]
\_cons      &      -3.135         &      -2.583         &       0.990         &       0.858         &      -1.513         \\
            &     (-1.44)         &     (-1.62)         &      (0.62)         &      (0.30)         &     (-0.44)         \\
\hline
\(N\)       &          44         &          22         &          44         &          44         &          22         \\
\(R^{2}\)   &       0.702         &       0.776         &       0.595         &       0.594         &       0.626         \\
\addlinespace
Fixed Effect            &         YES         &         NO      &          YES         &         YES       &         YES    \\
\midrule
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors are cluster by id.}\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So, just to be sure, you want to automatically parse the number into scientific notation? I'm pretty sure the siunitx package can do that.

Comment: Is `$7,42\times 10^{-5}$` what you want?

Answer (score 4):

You're inputting the specification for the `S` columns incorrectly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
detect-mode,
group-digits = false,
input-symbols = ( ) [ ] - +,
table-align-text-post = false,
input-signs = ,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\protected\def\sym#1{\rlap{\(^{#1}\)}}
\protected\def\symnote#1{\mbox{\(^{#1}\)}}
\caption{Innovation regressions using several diversity dimensions. \label{tabl}}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  *{5}{
    S[table-format=2.2e1,
      table-sign-mantissa=true,
      table-sign-exponent=true,
      scientific-notation=true]}
}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}\\
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Full sample}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Full sample}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Full sample}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Full sample}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Full sample}\\
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{div\_cont}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{div\_cont}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{div25\_cont}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{div25\_nat}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{div25\_nat\_obs}\\

\midrule

gdp\_pop
  & 0,0000742        & 0.0000327 & 0.000142\sym{*} & 0.000142\sym{*} & 0.0000913 \\
  &    (1.56)        &    (0.52) &   (2.32)        &   (2.32)        &    (1.24) \\[1em]
ind\_agri
  &   0.0127\sym{**} &    0.0100 &   0.0174\sym{*} &   0.0174\sym{*} & 0.0183\sym{**} \\
  &   (2.93)         &    (1.93) &    (2.71)       &   (2.71)        & (3.11)         \\[1em]
ln\_pop      &     -0.0158         &    -0.00404         &    -0.00720         &    -0.00708         &    -0.00881         \\
            &     (-1.20)         &     (-0.26)         &     (-0.34)         &     (-0.33)         &     (-0.31)         \\[1em]
size\_area   &   0.0000254\sym{*}  &  0.00000644         &   0.0000158         &   0.0000157         &   0.0000132         \\
            &      (2.17)         &      (0.46)         &      (0.91)         &      (0.90)         &      (0.57)         \\[1em]
human\_st    &      0.0515         &      0.0141         &     0.00257         &     0.00241         &      0.0505         \\
            &      (1.71)         &      (0.33)         &      (0.06)         &      (0.06)         &      (1.04)         \\[1em]
sh\_for\_pop  &       2.982         &       2.629         &      -3.222         &      -3.244         &      -3.605         \\
            &      (0.77)         &      (0.63)         &     (-0.62)         &     (-0.62)         &     (-0.81)         \\
[1em]
div\_cont    &       5.790\sym{*}  &       3.758         &                     &                     &                     \\
            &      (2.28)         &      (1.33)         &                     &                     &                     \\
[1em]
y2000       &      -0.279         &                     &      -0.469         &      -0.468         &                     \\
            &     (-1.11)         &                     &     (-1.20)         &     (-1.21)         &                     \\
[1em]
educ        &                     &      0.0489\sym{*}  &                     &                     &                     \\
            &                     &      (2.28)         &                     &                     &                     \\
[1em]

div25\_cont  &                     &                     &      0.0825         &                     &                     \\
            &                     &                     &      (0.12)         &                     &                     \\
[1em]
div25\_nat   &                     &                     &                     &       0.212         &                     \\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (0.07)         &                     \\
[1em]
div25\_nat\_obs&                     &                     &                     &                     &       2.391         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (0.96)         \\
[1em]
\_cons      &      -3.135         &      -2.583         &       0.990         &       0.858         &      -1.513         \\
            &     (-1.44)         &     (-1.62)         &      (0.62)         &      (0.30)         &     (-0.44)         \\
\midrule
\(N\)       &          44         &          22         &          44         &          44         &          22         \\
\(R^{2}\)   &       0.702         &       0.776         &       0.595         &       0.594         &       0.626         \\
\addlinespace
Fixed Effect            &         {YES}         &         {NO}      &          {YES}         &         {YES}       &         {YES}    \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors are cluster by id.}\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize \symnote{*} \(p<0.05\), \symnote{**} \(p<0.01\), \symnote{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the `S` column type automatically centers material that's encased in a pair of curly braces, one could replace all fifteen `\multicolumn{1}{c}{<arg>}` statements with just `{<arg>}`.

Comment: @Mico Of course; I put my attention to the numeric data.